# OpenShift hot deploy needs an app restart

Tags: php, openshift, hotdeploy

I set up my scaled PHP app to deploy by git push. Everything looks good, as far as I can see, but after the deployment is finished, the changes take no effect. I have to restart the app.

```
remote: Not stopping cartridge php because hot deploy is enabled
remote: Syncing git content to other proxy gears
remote: Building git ref 'beta', commit 1234567
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is 1234567
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Not starting cartridge haproxy because hot deploy is enabled
remote: Not starting cartridge php because hot deploy is enabled
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question - this was a bug in Openshift Online:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1225327